# Specify the conditions Exponent and Mantissa sizes must meet, so that the minimal distance between representable numbers is no more than 1.

Tags: binary, floating-point

Using the following floating-point representation:

- s - one sign bit
- m - mantissa - real number in range [1, 2), in which 1 and the comma are skipped, size of M bits
- c - Exponent - natural number, size of C bits

in which the numer is calculated as:
(-1)^s*m*2^c

We want to represent numbers from [-n, n] using this floating point representation, so that the maximum range of unrepresentable is 1. In other words: if numbers a,b are representable and there is no other representable numbers between them, then |b-a|<=1

What condition must numbers M and C meet (for a given n) for this condition to be true?